# MDX query output producing the same column multiple times

Tags: sql, sql-server, mdx, multidimensional-cube

I am using an MDX query in Power BI to extract data from SQL Server Analysis Services, but for some reason the query is repeating every column twice.

I don't have the knowledge of MDX query, so I used report builder for this.

The query:

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Premium LCL] } ON COLUMNS, 
  NON EMPTY { (
    [D_BU].[Business Unit Number].[Business Unit Number].ALLMEMBERS * 
    [D_Policy].[OriginalPolicyID].[OriginalPolicyID].ALLMEMBERS * 
    [D_Revenue_Attribute].[InsurerName].[InsurerName].ALLMEMBERS * 
    [D_Client].[ClientName].[ClientName].ALLMEMBERS * 
    [D_TransactionDate].[Accounting Month Number].[Accounting Month Number].ALLMEMBERS *    [D_TransactionDate].[Accounting Year].[Accounting Year].ALLMEMBERS * 
    [D_TransactionDate].[Accounting Month Year].[Accounting Month Year].ALLMEMBERS *    [D_PolicyExpirationDate].[Expiration Month Year].[Expiration Month Year].ALLMEMBERS *   [D_Policy].[InceptionDate].[InceptionDate].ALLMEMBERS * 
    [D_Product].[Product Line].[Product Line].ALLMEMBERS * 
    [D_Product].[Product Coverage].[Product Coverage].ALLMEMBERS * 
    [D_BU].[Region Name].[Region Name].ALLMEMBERS * 
    [D_BU].[Branch Name].[Branch Name].ALLMEMBERS * 
    [D_CarrierPayee].[Placement Market Group].[Placement Market Group].ALLMEMBERS *     [D_Industry_SIC].[SIC Level 2 Name].[SIC Level 2 Name].ALLMEMBERS *     
    [D_Industry_SIC].[SIC Level 3 Name].[SIC Level 3 Name].ALLMEMBERS 
       ) } DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, 
    MEMBER_VALUE,
    MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS 
FROM 
       ( 
    SELECT 
        ( 
            {[D_BU].[RegionName].&[GGB UK - Underwriting], 
            [D_BU].[RegionName].&[GGB UK - Specialty], 
            [D_BU].[RegionName].&[GGB(UK & Ireland)] } 
        ) ON COLUMNS 
FROM 
    ( 
     SELECT 
        ( 
            -{ [D_BU].[BranchName].&[Re Centre], 
            [D_BU].[BranchName].&[UK&Ireland] } 
        ) ON COLUMNS 
FROM 
    ( 
     SELECT 
        ( 
            { [D_TransactionDate].[Accounting Year].&[2023] } 
        ) ON COLUMNS 
FROM    
    [Model]
))) 
WHERE ( [D_BU].[RegionName].CurrentMember ) CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using MySQL? The above SQL looks more like for MS SQL Server.

Comment: It is MS SQL server analysis services